# Drawing regional polygons on google maps v3 API

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need to draw complex regional bounding polygons in google maps. Is there a way to easily access regional data to draw these polygons? The regions will be australian postcode areas. If you type a post code into google (not maps normal search) such as "2454" into google the first result is an image with the regional polygon (perhaps this search only works if your searching from australia). Im assuming this data is accessible as google is drawing the polygon.

any idea how i would access this bounds data?

an example of what im talking about is here

http://maps.google.com.au/maps?pq=australian+postcode+2454&hl=en&cp=0&gs_id=2&xhr=t&q=2454&safe=off&gs_upl=&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&biw=1876&bih=872&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hq=&hnear=0x6b9e9f724b020f8d:0x1c0609b7ccd310d0,New+South+Wales+2454&gl=au&ei=a3MoT66iKoKuiQelk7m3Ag&sa=X&oi=geocode_result&ct=title&resnum=2&sqi=2&ved=0CDIQ8gEwAQ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This data isn't available through the Google Maps API at this time. You would need to find a 3rd party provider of the boundary data. A quick query shows [several providers of the data](https://www.google.com/?q=australian%20postal%20code%20boundaries), though I'm not sure if they're provided anywhere for free. Once you get the data, it's probably in a GIS data format, such as a Shapefile or a KML file. These can be loaded into Google Fusion Tables or KML files can be loaded directly using a Google Maps API KMLLayer.

Comment: thanks.

I have found a source from the ABS that looks perfect and its free. You were right its in a GIS format. Is it possible to load this into a DB field somehow? thanks for the lead

Comment: If anyone would like more information of Australian postcode boundries and some complex distance calculations this link is golden... http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/917512

Comment: There are a lot of different database options out there. Or you can load it into Google Fusion Tables. If it's a Shapefile, you can use http://shpescape.com. If it's KML, you can just load it directly into Fusion Tables using the Google Docs interface.

Comment: I think Google does provide it now -- http://searchengineland.com/google-maps-now-highlighting-borders-of-cities-postal-codes-more-108589

Comment: Google Maps provides it, the maps api does not

Answer (score 0):

That data is not accessible programmatically from Google.  Your best bet is to either find KML for the data and then use either maps.google.com or the Google Maps API to load the KML (http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/layers.html#KMLLayers) or to use somehing like Fusion Tables to load GIS data (or KML) into a fusion table, and then use the Fusion Tables layer in the Google Maps API (http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/layers.html#FusionTables).

**Note that the Fusion Tables layer is experimental.*

Comment: what are fusion table layers?

Comment: @AndrewMcLagan http://www.google.com/fusiontables/Home/  They are nifty GDocs Spreadsheets with geocoding minus all of the normal spreadsheet functions.