# Google Maps API Highlight Geographical Area Data

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geolocation

I want to be able to show outlines of postal codes, cities/suburbs and states/territories in Australia via Google Maps.  The idea would be so give the user a way to click within the area to select it.

I understand that I can create an overlay to show the outlines, but to do so, I need data to draw the outlines.

I noticed when I search on Google, then click the maps result, it highlights the city/suburb/state.  This seems to work for all of the suburbs I have tried in Australia, as well as for US states/cities.

Here is an example:[image: Denver Outline]

So, my question is:  How do I find the data I need to do this and/or can I somehow rely on the Google Maps API to get this data for me?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Thanks to @Mano_Marks, here is a data source provided by the AU government:  http://www.abs.gov.au/AUSSTATS/abs@.nsf/DetailsPage/1259.0.30.0022006?OpenDocument

Now I just need to figure out how to actually use this to build overlays with Google Maps.

Comment: Check out this question right here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9088429/1073772

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what is the cleanest way to do but you can upload those KML files or something to Google fusion table. They provide an API to style polygons from your datasets.

and you can do somthing like

```
    layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
        query: {
          select: 'geometry',
          from: 'your data ID',
        },
        styles:[],
      });
```

and

```
layer.styles.push({strokewidth:xxx, strokecolor:yy, fillOpacity: blahblah});
```

go check this https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers